# ELMo - How to train trainable parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, elmo

I am new to tensorflow-hub and came across the ELMo model (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/elmo/2).

According to the original paper, the ELMo representation is a weighted average of hidden state activations and these weights are trainable according to the task at hand i.e task specific. As expected, I can see the 4 trainable parameters when I use tf.trainable_variables(). How do I exactly train these variables in tensorflow?

They just mention that these weights are trainable. But who should train it? Me or ELMo model itself trains it? The paper seems to suggest that I should be training it. If so, how do I train it in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can start off by importing a module into your model with trainable=True, then [train](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/get_started/mnist/mechanics) the model as you would any other TF model. In the process of this training the model the weight imported a part of the module will be trained as well. You can also use [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text_classification_with_tf_hub) as a good starting point as well, and just replace nnlm embedding with ELMo.